# Null value cannot be inserted

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to insert this file on mySql database.I already allowed nulls on my database still I get this errors.

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'orderId', table 'MejOnlineManagementDB00.dbo.orders2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO orders2
                            (orderName,orderFile,orderPrice,orderQuantity,orderShipped)
                            VALUES
                            ('"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue+"','"+lblFile.Text+"','"+lblPrice.Text
                            +"','"+txtQuantity.Text+"','"+DateTime.Now+"')",con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblFinished.Text = "Order has been submitted for process.";

    }
```

Comment: It looks like `orderId` does not allow NULLs. This is probably the primary key, so that makes sense. Maybe you can set `orderId` to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: @Wimmel You could not set the primary to be null value right?or you could?

Comment: change the `orderId` column to be `IDENTITY`

Comment: @rainalasa See [Why primary key cannot contain null values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25701288/33499)

Comment: Mark the primary key column as auto_increment identity column.